# LINQ - .Split(new[] { ' ' }) string and set default value if found null

Tags: c#, linq, split

Here is my LINQ query

```
var listLogOutItems = 
    (from A in data 
     orderby A.FirstName 
     select new { 
         Login = "Logout",
         Name = A.FirstName + " " + A.SurName,
         ID = A.Id,
         LogoutDate = A.LogOutTime.Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[0]
     }).Distinct();
```

if A.LogOutTime is null then return "Unknown". How can do this?

Comment: Please try to avoid horizontal scrolling in SO questions. I've reformatted your code appropriately (so there's only a *little* bit of scrolling).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way is probably to use the null coalescing operator `??`.

```
LogoutDate = (A.LogOutTime ?? "Unknown").Split(...)[0]
```

If `A.LogOutTime` is `null`, it'll use `"Unknown"` instead. This is slightly inefficient as it will be calling `Split` on a string we know doesn't need splitting... in C# 6 you could use the null conditional operator instead:

```
LogoutDate = A.LogOutTime?.Split(...)[0] ?? "Unknown"
```

Here, if `A.LogOutTime` is `null`, `Split` won't be evaluated, and the result of that part of the expression will be `null` - then the null coalescing operator is used just at the end.

As an aside, rather than creating a new `char[]` every time, you might as well just have a static field:

```
private static readonly ArrayWithSpace = new[] { ' ' };
```

Then reuse that on every call to `Split`.

Comment: @HenkHolterman: Not for that overload - it can't be, because only the final parameter can be a `params` parameter. (And even if you could, it would still pointlessly create a new array on every iteration.)

Comment: I have tried above code, its working one condition but this condition 
            var listLogOutItems = (from A in data orderby A.FirstName select new { Login = "Logout", Name = A.FirstName + " " + A.SurName, ID = A.Id, LogoutDate = (A.LogOutTime ?? "Unknown").Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[0], LogoutTime = (A.LogOutTime ?? "Unknown").Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[1] + " " + (A.LogOutTime ?? " ").Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[2], Comments = "Never delete this Archive" }).Distinct();

Not working.

Comment: @AbhilashJA: "Not working" is *never* enough description for what you're seeing. Now the reason is pretty obvious - why you split "Unknown" you only get one entry, but you're asking for the second one. Don't do that. But aside from anything else, it sounds like you should have another `select` before this one to transform a null value of `A.LogOutTime` into *one* appropriate unknown value, e.g. "Unknown Unkonwn Unknown" and then you don't need to repeat this all the time.

Comment: Error occured. "The index was out of the bound of the array"

Comment: @AbhilashJA: Right, as I thought. Now, before asking for more help, did you try to think about *why* the index would be outside the bounds of the array? If you understood my answer, you should have been able to work out why it was going wrong and what the solution would be.